# Multiple submit inputs, do something based on which one was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have hit a road block. I have 3 different buttons `submit`, `delete` and `cancel` inside a form. Depending on which one was hit, it should get the inputs name or id. My current code for the delete button is this.

```
if ($("input[value=delete]").click()) {
    myApp.alert($(this).attr("name"));
    myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Delete Staff', function () {
        check_url(url, "delete");

    });
    return false;
}
```

Here is the `check_url()` function, if it will help:

```
function check_url(recieve_url, type) {
    if (recieve_url == undefined || recieve_url == null) {
        alert("recieve_url is not set!");
    }
    $.ajax({
        url : recieve_url,
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'json',
        data : "type="+type,
        success : function (result) {
            //alert(result['bg'] + result['message'] + result['caption'])
            myApp.alert(result['message'], result['title']);
            if (result['redirect'] != null || result['redirect'] != undefined){
                window.location = "<?php echo $this->url;?>"+result['redirect'];
            }
            //notify_response(result['message'], result['bg'], result['caption']);
        },
        error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            myApp.alert(xhr.responseText);
            myApp.alert(xhr.status);
            myApp.alert(thrownError);
        }
    })

}
```

I have tried an `else if` and use `"input[value=submit]"`, but the other submit buttons will use this `delete` one instead. Is there something I'm currently missing?

### **Edit**

```
<form onsubmit="return submit_edit(this.action);" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->url."Staff/EditSubmit/".$value['id']; ?>">
    <div class="content-block-title"><?php echo $value['first_name'].' '.$value['last_name']?></div>
    <div class="list-block inset">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title label">Phone Number</div>
                        <div class="item-input">
                            <input type="tel" value="<?php echo $value['phone_number']?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title label">Address</div>
                        <div class="item-input">
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $value['address']?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="label-checkbox item-content">
                    <!-- Checked by default -->
                    <?php if($value['admin'] == 1): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="admin_check" value="true" checked="checked">
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="admin_check" value="false">
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <div class="item-media">
                        <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title">Admin</div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="label-checkbox item-content">
                    <!-- Checked by default -->
                    <?php if($value['staff'] == 1): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="staff_check" value="true" checked="checked">
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="staff_check" value="false">
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <div class="item-media">
                        <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title">Staff</div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="label-checkbox item-content">
                    <!-- Checked by default -->
                    <?php if($value['disabled'] == 1): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="disabled_check" value="true" checked="checked">
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="disabled_check" value="false">
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <div class="item-media">
                        <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title">Disabled</div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="label-checkbox item-content">
                    <!-- Checked by default -->
                    <?php if($value['active'] == 1): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="active_check" value="true" checked="checked">
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="active_check" value="false">
                    <?php endif ?>
                    <div class="item-media">
                        <i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-inner">
                        <div class="item-title">Active</div>
                    </div>
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="list-block inset">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-33">
                <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="button button-big button-fill color-green">
            </div>
            <div class="col-33">
                <input id="delete" type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" class="button button-big button-fill color-red">
            </div>
            <div class="col-33">
                <input id="cancel" type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel" class="button button-big button-fill color-blue">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the following function:

```
function submit_edit(url) {
    if ($("input[value=delete]").click()) {
        myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Delete Staff', function () {
            check_url(url, "delete");
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

I forgot to include the function name at the beginning.

Comment: Attach the same handler to all of the buttons and test their names within.

Comment: I got the problem, you are saying in `if($("input[value=delete]").click())` so this condition will always be true, because you are saying triggering click event of button having value `delete`, instead check somehow that this button is clicked.

Comment: I actually have never seen something like this: `if ($("input[value=delete]").click())`

Comment: @Mritunjay, what could I do to make that not be true all the time?

Comment: Boolean($("input[value=delete]")) is true, also $("input[value=delete]") will trigger delete button click and thats why you are only receiving delete button's trigger

Comment: Why dont you specify `onclick()` methods inline pointing to 2 different functions??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to point all the buttons to a common place, but change something slightly depending on which one has been clicked, you do it like this:

```
$(function () {
    // A single click event handler to all the submit buttons.
    $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function (event) {
        // Prevent the default behavior for the form submit.
        event.preventDefault();

        // The value of the clicked one.
        var buttonValue = $(this).attr('value');

        // Carry on with your code...
        if (buttonValue == 'delete') {
            myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Delete Staff', function () {
                check_url(url, "delete");
            });   
        }
        else if (buttonValue == 'submit') {

        }
        else {

        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE**

After chatting in the comments, I believe that's what you're after actually:

Add this to your form:

```
<!-- This field will hold which submit button has been clicked -->
<input type="hidden" name="clicked" id="clicked" value="" />
```

And change your script:

```
function submit_edit(url) {
    // Check which submit button has been clicked
    // by getting the hidden input value.
    var value = $('#clicked').val();

    if (value == 'delete') {
        myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Delete Staff', function () {
            check_url(url, "delete");
        });   
    }
    else if (buttonValue == 'submit') {

    }
    else {

    }
}

$(function () {
    // A single click event handler to all the submit buttons.
    $('input[type=submit]').on('click', function () {
        // The value of the clicked one.
        var buttonValue = $(this).attr('value');

        // Store the value in the hidden field.
        $('#clicked').val(buttonValue);
    });
});
```

Comment: When I use this and click the delete button, it goes to the form action URL. Is there a place where I'm missing a `return false;`?

Comment: Try the updated code, please. It would be useful to see your markup to give you an exact answer. :)

Comment: If on any condition you actually need to submit the form, just trigger it: `$('form').submit();`

Comment: @MelanciaUK, I added the markup to the original post.

Comment: I got it to work, how would I nest it inside the `submit_edit()` function?

Comment: Well it works when I leave it outside the `submit_edit()` function. But when I put the entire script inside the function it continues to the form action URL.

Comment: But this is an event handler. When you click any of the submit buttons, it will be called. If you need the form to submit, you need to trigger it inside this handler like I said.

Comment: But if you want to do the checks after the form is submitted, you need to stop handling the click events.

Comment: With a little bit of editing, I was able to make it work. Thank you!

Comment: I tried yours, and it went through with the action. I noticed there wasn't a `event.preventDefault();` anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the click-event using an event handler instead of a conditional-statement, like so:

```js
$("input[value=delete]").click(function() {
    myApp.alert($(this).attr("name"));
    myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Delete Staff', function () {
        check_url(url, "delete");
    });
    return false;
});
```

...because `if ($("input[value=delete]").click())` will always return `true`.

The reason: you're effectively *raising* a `click()`-event instead of checking for an existing condition. But... you still get a response that causes the condition check to return `true` and that's why this bit of code always runs no matter what button you click :)

You could also grab clicks on all buttons using this:

```js
$("input").click(function() {
    // Check for value of $(this).attr("value") and act accordingly
    if ($(this).attr("value") == "delete") 
    {
        // Do delete-stuff
    }
    else if ($(this).attr("value") == "submit") 
    {
        // Do other stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this i guess:

```
$("input[value=delete]").click(function(){
    myApp.alert($(this).attr("name"));
    myApp.confirm('Are you sure?', 'Delete Staff', function () {
        check_url(url, "delete");
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you bind different function calls to different input tags. Like:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="javascript:SubmitClicked(parameters)">
```

And for a delete button

```
<input type="submit" value="Delete" onclick="javascript:DeleteClicked(parameters)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you usually don't want to have multiple submit buttons on a form (as you're experiencing, which one triggers the submit can be problematic).  Instead, opt for one submit button and two other buttons.  In addition to this, I would remove the `onclick` attribute from your form (it is unnecessary and if you target the click events of the buttons themselves it is redundant as well).

You should treat submit as what happens **after** you've done any pre-processing so binding to click events, then conditionally raising the submit is better than always submitting but conditionally stopping the submit.

That being said, you can bind to the click event of the buttons and the submit using code like the following:

What you need is to use JQuery's event argument to help you identify the source, like so:

```
<div id="actions">
    <form>
        <input type="submit" id="first-button" value="Submit" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="second-button" value="Delete" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" id="third-button" value="Cancel" />
    </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    //Setup the click for all of the buttons (these could be hyperlinks or any other element as well).
    $("#actions").find("input[type='submit'], input[type='button']").click(function (e) {
        //Do some conditional stuff based on the element that triggered the event
        var sender = $(e.currentTarget);
        switch (sender.val()) {
            case "Delete":
                var shouldDelete = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?");
                break;
            case "Submit":
                alert("Submit clicked.");
                $("#actions").find("form").submit();
                break;
            case "Cancel":
                alert("Cancelled.");
                break;
            default:
                alert("Unknown clicked.");
                break;
        } // end switch
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/rhLdxjzj/

JQuery's event argument `e` has lots of useful information about which element triggered the event. See the JQuery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/on/